# How to determine what weapons can I craft?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

In Alpha 13, you no longer have a recipe for mechanical weapons (pistols, rifles, etc.) but instead, you click on a found part, and you have an "Assemble" option, where you can remove/replace parts on that weapon. If you fill all of the required slots, you click "Close" and the weapon is crafted.

The issue that I have is that I know I've read several recipes, like the sniper rifle and pistol, but since they don't show up on my crafting list, how can I possibly know which ones I've learned without writing them down externally to the game?

Normally I'd just read everything I find so it's a non-issue, but I'm in desperate need of paper, so I'd really like to scrap anything that I don't need to read. Without remembering that I know any particular schematic, is there any other way of knowing which ones I have already learned?

Also, I see the learned/total ratio in the crafting screen, that looks like 45/65 recipes learned or whatever. Does that 65 number (or whatever the max number is, I'm not able to check right now) include all of the above schematics? In other words, when it reads 65/65, do I know that I can craft literally anything in the whole game?

Comment: I had the same issue but luckily in A14 they added the text "Known" to all the schematics/recipes :)

Comment: Even the "assemble" plans like rifle and pistol?

Comment: Yup, the pistol and sniper rifle, etc.. all say now "Recipe: Known" if you already know them in the description box.

Comment: The issue isn't knowing if I need a recipe that I found (ie the "Known" recipes), but I'd like to have a list of the ones I don't have. A sort of "shopping list". I guess I could have an external note that contains that kind of thing, but I'd like to see it in-game.

Comment: That would be nice. I can bring it up and ask if that is something they plan on doing or ask the modders from the mods I play if that is something that could be modded in. Theoretically all the info is in the xml files, though it depends if there is a lookup of known recipes that can be done or if each recipe as it spawns checks separately.